# Paypal-Sandbox buying with Selenium RC

Tags: selenium-rc, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to buy something at Paypal-Sandbox with Selenium RC (Java), but it doesn't work.

I tried it with Selenium IDE (Firefox AddOn) and it did work. I changed the viewing and copied the JUnit 4 Code and it still doesn't work.

The problem is the part with the radio-button "payment_type_paypal". Somehow it doesnt work in RC (the radio-button is not checked). Do someone have similiar experiences and/or resolved the issue?

After loging in to developer.paypal.com and entering the homepage...

```
//linking homepage

selenium.click("legalTerms");

selenium.click("pay");

selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");

//leaving homepage and switching to paypal

selenium.click("payment_type_paypal"); // <===== point of error

selenium.type("login_email",username);

selenium.type("login_password",pw);
```

Thx :)

Answer (score 2):

its me againg, Krzys. I know now the Problem. Its an issue with focussing the correct frame. I couldn't get it work with Selenium RC.

You can easily fix the issue in Selenium WebDriver with the command, before my "point of error":

```
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Answer (score 2):

its me again. If you encounter problems with the Sandbox System of Paypal, you can overcome the "submit"-button issues using xpath.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='nav-menu']/form/ul/li/ul/li[6]/input")
```

Greetz
Krzys